# Broadcasting intents from a remote process service

Tags: android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver, remote-process

I have a service that is defined to run on it's own process:

```
<service
            android:name="com.package.MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:process=":remote">
```

and I have a class that runs that service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        intent.setAction(Constants.ACTION);
        context.startService(intent);
```

I am trying to broadcast an `Intent`as following:

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(RECEIVER);
        broadcastIntent.setAction(action);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra(DATA, msg);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

here I declare my receiver:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //doSomething
    };
```

but it seems like the onReceive is never called

Comment: Where are you registering this receiver?

Comment: when I instantiate the class. It gets in the constructor a Context (this is a Unity3D project)

Comment: How exactly are you registering the Receiver? It looks like you're instantiating your broadcast `Intent` with one action, then setting another. You sure you've got the correct `IntentFilter` for your Receiver?

Comment: `context.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
                Constants.RECEIVER));`
and `Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(RECEIVER);
        broadcastIntent.setAction(action);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra(DATA, msg);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);`

Comment: That would probably be the problem, then, or, at least one of them. An `Intent` can only have one action. You instantiate the broadcast `Intent` with `RECEIVER`, but then you change it to `action`. You're filtering for `RECEIVER`, which presumably is not the same as `action`.